# How to add time series objects (ts) in a data.table, by row?

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I'm trying to store ts objects by row.  The monthly data (24 monthly values for 1980 and 1981) for creating the time series are stored in a  row-wise order in DT, so I just want to add a column in DT to store the "ts" objects () for each row.  Here's a reproducible example where I tried three different options but none of them seems to work as I expected.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID=seq(1:10),
                 JAN_1980=rnorm(1:10),FEB_1980=rnorm(1:10),MAR_1980=rnorm(1:10),APR_1980=rnorm(1:10),MAY_1980=rnorm(1:10),JUN_1980=rnorm(1:10),JUL_1980=rnorm(1:10),AUG_1980=rnorm(1:10),SEP_1980=rnorm(1:10),OCT_1980=rnorm(1:10),NOV_1980=rnorm(1:10),DEC_1980=rnorm(1:10),JAN_1981=rnorm(1:10),FEB_1981=rnorm(1:10),MAR_1981=rnorm(1:10),APR_1981=rnorm(1:10),MAY_1981=rnorm(1:10),JUN_1981=rnorm(1:10),JUL_1981=rnorm(1:10),AUG_1981=rnorm(1:10),SEP_1981=rnorm(1:10),OCT_1981=rnorm(1:10),NOV_1981=rnorm(1:10),DEC_1981=rnorm(1:10))

# First attempt
DT[,TS_COL:=ts(.SD[,2:25,with=FALSE], start=c(1980,1), frequency=12)]

# Second
DT[,TS_COL:=ts(unlist(.SD[,2:25,with=FALSE]), start=c(1980,1), frequency=12)]

# Third
DT[,TS_COL:=list(list(list(ts(unlist(.SD[,2:25,with=FALSE]), start=c(1980,1), frequency=12))))]
```

I'd like to be able to access a ts object for a specific row in this way (no luck yet):

```
DT[1,TS_COL]
```

...and get something like (2 years of monthly data):

```
             Jan         Feb         Mar         Apr         May         Jun         Jul         Aug         Sep         Oct         Nov         Dec
1980  2.13303849  0.74954206 -0.45112504  2.13558888  1.11883498 -0.39074470  1.77374480 -0.19513901  0.49920019 -1.12875185  0.45598049  1.97730211
1981  0.62764761 -0.86330094 -0.51585664  0.59677770 -0.71073980 -0.26208961 -0.38833227  1.39841244 -1.50490225 -0.72018921  1.06684672  0.07126184
```

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Comment: what are the rows in your original data.table?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's not really what data.table was designed for.

Comment: This is very doable with a transposed dataset. Why are you unable to carry this out beforehand?

Comment: If you don't mind transposing `lapply(as.data.frame(t(DT[,-1, with=F])), function(x) ts(x, start=c(1980,1), freq=12))`

Comment: @mtoto Each row is a location (ID) with monthly values (JAN1980-DEC1981)... I just need to add a column that can hold a 'ts' object for each location, because then I want to pass a 'ts' object to a function for each location.

Comment: @PierreLafortune So, I have seen examples where you see <list> as the content of a cell... Have you tried to get <ts> instead?

Answer (score 8):

I can't remember ever using `ts()` myself. I tend to have irregular time series stored long format. Either a single datetime column, or a date column and time column separately (for rolling to the prevailing observation within a day but not to the previous day). Then I create a regularly spaced time series and join that to the data, or find the beginning and end of windows using `which` and `roll` and extract the subset for that window.

That said, let's try with `ts()`.

Please include the error or warning message in your question. See items 6 and 7 on the [Support page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support). Your example is not reproducible; i.e. I get the following warnings but it's feasible you're getting a different warning (you didn't include it, so there's nothing to attempt to reproduce).  Neither is the example minimal because we don't need 20 columns that wrap around the console output.

```
DT[,TS_COL:=ts(.SD[,2:25,with=FALSE], start=c(1980,1), frequency=12)]
# Warning messages:
# 1: In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(TS_COL, ts(.SD[, 2:25, with = FALSE],  :
# 24 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
# 2: In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(TS_COL, ts(.SD[, 2:25, with = FALSE],  :
#  Supplied 240 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'TS_COL' (230 unused)
```

First things first, let's look at the manual.  `?ts` contains the following signature:

> ts(data = NA, start = 1, end = numeric(), frequency = 1,
>      deltat = 1, ts.eps = getOption("ts.eps"), class = , names = )

You're using the first argument `data` so under that it says :

> data: a vector or matrix of the observed time-series values. A data frame will be coerced to a numeric matrix via data.matrix. (See also ‘Details’.)

Since a data.table inherits from data.frame, it is a data.frame too. Therefore the data.table will be coerced to a matrix.

Further down, we see something about matrix :

> In the matrix case, each column of the matrix data is assumed to contain a single (univariate) time series.

Now let's split the problem up and inspect the RHS it's trying to assign. Simply remove the `TS_COL:=` part and run it again to return the RHS so we can have a look at it.

```
RHS = DT[,ts(.SD[,2:25,with=FALSE], start=c(1980,1), frequency=12)]
class(RHS)
# [1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix"
dim(RHS)
# [1] 10 24
dim(DT)
# [1] 10 26
length(RHS)
# [1] 240
storage.mode(RHS)
# [1] "double"
```

So it's a matrix.  And worse it is `double` and not `integer`. (Recall we don't like `Date` in base either for use in data.table because, oddly, `Date` is `double` rather than `integer`.)

You can't store a matrix as a column in data.table. data.table treats the matrix as the vector it is internally, which the warning messages (shown above in this answer) are alluding to. Here are the warning messages again :

```
24 column matrix RHS of := will be treated as one vector
Supplied 240 items to be assigned to 10 items of column 'TS_COL' (230 unused)
```

These warnings are created by data.table code and are pretty good I think.

So if you are to proceed with using the `ts()` class as a column of data.table then you need to either coerce the matrix to a list of 24 columns (24 vectors all 10 long) rather than a matrix of 24 columns (internally one vector 240 long).

But at this point it seems the `ts()` class is not the right tool for the job.  What do you really need to do?  Better to back up and describe what the bigger picture is.

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Ok,  my goal is to use "ts" object as input for spei function (drought index, package spei), for a lot of rows (locations). I guess I'll try to pass a ts built on the fly... I just wanted to pre-generate the ts for each location, so I can use something like "mclapply" to run spei across all my points (rows). However, I'm still not sure if that approach will work, just was exploring options with DT.